# Already an object named "Accounts" in the database (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have looked at the other questions with this title but they all say to delete the table.  I don't want to delete it, it has important data.

Instead, can't I make MVC stop trying to recreate it in the first place?  I just want to read its data and output it.  I am just trying to output it like this:

```
return View(db.Accounts.ToList());
```

This is my model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public class Account
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How can I stop MVC from trying to recreate my table?

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: I have an out-of-the-box ASP.NET MVC 4 application.  I don't want to use code first, since my database is already built.  I am not sure if I am using EF or not...

Comment: Does your account object match the accounts table in the database

Comment: In what way?  My table in the database is `ACCOUNTS` and it has a lot more fields.  I just want to test it out by listing only the `ID` field.  Is this not possible?

Comment: @user1477388 can you use 2 different "databases"?

Comment: @DaveA I don't know what you mean.  I am only trying to use, and I only intend to use my current and only database.

Answer (score 2):

What is happening is MVC is checking the database and seeing that you do not have an account object in the database with only one column, ID in your case. So MVC is trying to create that object for you. What you need to do in order to use the existing table structure is to make your object match what is already in the database.

You can also create a temporary database and create your object with only one property(column). That allow you to see if your connection string is correct.

Comment: Oh crap!  I feared that would be the case; this table has a ton of fields that I would have to manually type in.  Is there anyway to quickly type in all the fields into my model/ circumvent having to do so?

Comment: Good idea, Robert.  I will consider doing so.  Thanks.

Comment: exactly. I was pointing out that you could use another schema or db to have your cake and eat it too. But @Robert s point basically on. Well put +1

Answer (score 2):

Try to map the your account class to the existing table by overriding the `OnModelCreating()` method in your context class

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Account>( ).ToTable( "dbo.Accounts" );
        //and perhaps the columns as well
        modelBuilder.Entity<Account>( ).Property( p => p.Id )
                                       .HasColumnName( "Id" );
}
```

That should tell Entity Framework to use your existing table, rather that try to create a new one.  Mapping every column shouldn't be necessary.

Be sure the strings you pass to the `ToTable()` and `HasColumnName()` methods match exactly what is in your database.

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure if it will work because I just used a simpler table instead or using this one, but it looks like it is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

in the Global.asax put the following line in the Application_Start()

Database.SetInitializer(null);

this will prevent from creating the table
I hope that helps